# Codeigniter switch data between 2 views and update the database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, mysqli

I am trying to create a substitution for the fantansy footbal site i am building. i have a view that display 11 starting players and 4 on the bench.Here is my fantansyteam table.

```
teamID |  fantasyteam     | userID | GK1 | GK2 | DEF1 | DEF2 | MID1 | MID2 | FWD1 | FWD2
95        Washindi FC          1      13     2     3       6      7     12      15    18
```

so for example by default GK1 is starting and GK2 is on the bench , i want to switch their values. Here is my view....

```
<div class = "starting11">
    <?php echo base_url() ?>/team/substitution/<?php echo $gk1['playerName'];?>
</div>

<div class = "bench">
    <?php echo base_url() ?>/team/substitution/<?php echo $gk2['playerName'];?>
</div>
```

I am super confused on how to achieve this,i could create a controller that take GK1 and GK2 variables and insert them to a different column but i want the best way of achieving this. would appreciate any help....

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

1. Make a AJAX call in your page to the substitution controller
   which takes the substitutes details as input
2. Return the new composition of the team from the controller output.
3. Use the returned data in the AJAX call back function to update the screen.